# ROS c++ Class Subscriber doesn't work while publishing in constructor

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The following code subscribes to  topics containing data of individual wheel angular velocities, I am simply combining them and publishing the Odometry of the base_link.

I've been trying to do everything in the class itself but when I am running the While loop which is publishing the Odometry in the constructor the Subscriber Callback functions don't work.
In the following code callback functions don't work. While rostopic info shows that I am subscribing to those topics but the callbacks just don't run.

When I remove the while loop from the constructor and place it inside one of the callbacks , Everything runs smoothly

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include <stdio.h>

class Wheelodom
{
public:
  
  Wheelodom()
  {
    pub1 = n_.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 5);
    sub1 = n_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("left_wheel_odom", 10, &Wheelodom::odomCallback_l, this);
    sub2 = n_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("right_wheel_odom", 10, &Wheelodom::odomCallback_r, this);
    initialize();
    reset_pose();
    ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
      calculate_vel();
      ROS_INFO("%f", av_l);
      calculate_delta_pose();
      calculate_integrated_pose();
      publish_odom();
      loop_rate.sleep();
    } 

  }
  
  void initialize()
  {
    simba_link = "base_link";
    odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    cur_time = ros::Time::now();
    prev_time = ros::Time::now();
    Wheel_radius_r = 0.065;
    Wheel_radius_l = 0.065;
    rear_axle = 0.21;
    h = 0.07;
    av_l = 0.0;
    av_r = 0.0;
  }
  void reset_pose()
  {
    odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
  }
    
  void odomCallback_l(const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped::ConstPtr& data)
  {
    
    av_l = data->twist.linear.x;
    ROS_INFO("data received");
    
  }
  
  void odomCallback_r(const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped::ConstPtr& data)
  {
    
    av_r = data->twist.linear.x;
    
  }
  
  void calculate_vel()
  {
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = ((av_l*Wheel_radius_l) + (av_r*Wheel_radius_r))/2;
    odom.twist.twist.angular.z = ((av_r*Wheel_radius_r) - (av_l*Wheel_radius_l))/rear_axle;
  }
  
  void calculate_delta_pose()
  {
    cur_time = ros::Time::now();
    elapsed_time = cur_time-prev_time;
    prev_time = cur_time;
    delta_odom_pose.theta =  odom.twist.twist.angular.z * elapsed_time.toSec();
    delta_odom_pose.x = odom.twist.twist.linear.x * elapsed_time.toSec() * cos(odom_pose.theta + delta_odom_pose.theta * 0.5);
    delta_odom_pose.y = odom.twist.twist.linear.x * elapsed_time.toSec() * sin(odom_pose.theta + delta_odom_pose.theta * 0.5);
    
  }
  
  void calculate_integrated_pose()
  {
    odom_pose.x += delta_odom_pose.x;
    odom_pose.y += delta_odom_pose.y;
    odom_pose.theta += delta_odom_pose.theta;
    odom.pose.pose.position.x = odom_pose.x;
    odom.pose.pose.position.y = odom_pose.y;
    odom.pose.pose.position.z = h;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.z = sin(0.5 * odom_pose.theta); 
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.w = cos(0.5 * odom_pose.theta);
    
  }
  
  void publish_odom()
  {
    odom.header.frame_id = "w_odom";
    odom.child_frame_id = simba_link;
    odom.header.stamp = cur_time;
    pub1.publish(odom);
  }
  
private:
  ros::NodeHandle n_; 
  ros::Publisher pub1;
  ros::Subscriber sub1, sub2;
  std::string simba_link;
  nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
  float Wheel_radius_r,Wheel_radius_l;
  float rear_axle;
  float av_l,av_r,h; //angular velocities
  ros::Duration elapsed_time;
  ros::Time cur_time;
  ros::Time prev_time;
  geometry_msgs::Pose2D delta_odom_pose;
  geometry_msgs::Pose2D odom_pose;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "simba_wheel_odom");
  Wheelodom odomObject;
  //odomObject
//  odomObject.initialize();
//  odomObject.reset_pose();
//  ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
//  while(ros::ok())
//  {
//    odomObject.calculate_vel();
    //ROS_INFO("%f", av_l);
//    odomObject.calculate_delta_pose();
//    odomObject.calculate_integrated_pose();
//    odomObject.publish_odom();
//    loop_rate.sleep();
//  }

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

When I remove the while loop from the constructor and place it inside one of the callbacks , Everything runs smoothly

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include <stdio.h>

class Wheelodom
{
public:
  
  Wheelodom()
  {
    pub1 = n_.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 5);
    sub1 = n_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("left_wheel_odom", 10, &Wheelodom::odomCallback_l, this);
    sub2 = n_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("right_wheel_odom", 10, &Wheelodom::odomCallback_r, this);
    initialize();
    reset_pose();
    ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
//    while(ros::ok())
//    {
//      
//      loop_rate.sleep();
//   }

  }
  
  void initialize()
  {
    simba_link = "base_link";
    odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    cur_time = ros::Time::now();
    prev_time = ros::Time::now();
    Wheel_radius_r = 0.065;
    Wheel_radius_l = 0.065;
    rear_axle = 0.21;
    h = 0.07;
    av_l = 0.0;
    av_r = 0.0;
  }
  void reset_pose()
  {
    odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.x = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.y = 0.0;
    delta_odom_pose.theta = 0.0;
  }
    
  void odomCallback_l(const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped::ConstPtr& data)
  {
    
    av_l = data->twist.linear.x;
    ROS_INFO("data received");
    
  }
  
  void odomCallback_r(const geometry_msgs::TwistStamped::ConstPtr& data)
  {
    
    av_r = data->twist.linear.x;
    calculate_vel();
    ROS_INFO("%f", av_l);
    calculate_delta_pose();
    calculate_integrated_pose();
    publish_odom();
  }
  
  void calculate_vel()
  {
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = ((av_l*Wheel_radius_l) + (av_r*Wheel_radius_r))/2;
    odom.twist.twist.angular.z = ((av_r*Wheel_radius_r) - (av_l*Wheel_radius_l))/rear_axle;
  }
  
  void calculate_delta_pose()
  {
    cur_time = ros::Time::now();
    elapsed_time = cur_time-prev_time;
    prev_time = cur_time;
    delta_odom_pose.theta =  odom.twist.twist.angular.z * elapsed_time.toSec();
    delta_odom_pose.x = odom.twist.twist.linear.x * elapsed_time.toSec() * cos(odom_pose.theta + delta_odom_pose.theta * 0.5);
    delta_odom_pose.y = odom.twist.twist.linear.x * elapsed_time.toSec() * sin(odom_pose.theta + delta_odom_pose.theta * 0.5);
    
  }
  
  void calculate_integrated_pose()
  {
    odom_pose.x += delta_odom_pose.x;
    odom_pose.y += delta_odom_pose.y;
    odom_pose.theta += delta_odom_pose.theta;
    odom.pose.pose.position.x = odom_pose.x;
    odom.pose.pose.position.y = odom_pose.y;
    odom.pose.pose.position.z = h;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.z = sin(0.5 * odom_pose.theta); 
    odom.pose.pose.orientation.w = cos(0.5 * odom_pose.theta);
    
  }
  
  void publish_odom()
  {
    odom.header.frame_id = "w_odom";
    odom.child_frame_id = simba_link;
    odom.header.stamp = cur_time;
    pub1.publish(odom);
  }
  
private:
  ros::NodeHandle n_; 
  ros::Publisher pub1;
  ros::Subscriber sub1, sub2;
  std::string simba_link;
  nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
  float Wheel_radius_r,Wheel_radius_l;
  float rear_axle;
  float av_l,av_r,h; //angular velocities
  ros::Duration elapsed_time;
  ros::Time cur_time;
  ros::Time prev_time;
  geometry_msgs::Pose2D delta_odom_pose;
  geometry_msgs::Pose2D odom_pose;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "simba_wheel_odom");
  Wheelodom odomObject;
  //odomObject
//  odomObject.initialize();
//  odomObject.reset_pose();
//  ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
//  while(ros::ok())
//  {
//    odomObject.calculate_vel();
    //ROS_INFO("%f", av_l);
//    odomObject.calculate_delta_pose();
//    odomObject.calculate_integrated_pose();
//    odomObject.publish_odom();
//    loop_rate.sleep();
//  }

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299002/ros-c++-class-subscriber-doesn%27t-work-while-publishing-in-constructor/) by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-30**:
Never, ever put infinite whiles in constructors or callbacks. Ever. It leads to exactly the problems that you describe / experienced.

Re-enable the while in your `main(..)`. Or use an `AsyncSpinner`.

**Comment by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on 2018-07-30**:
Uncommenting those portions inside main also leads to the same problem i.e : subscriber callbacks don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which is expected, as you don't have a `ros::spinOnce()` anywhere in the while-loop.

If you need a separate while-loop, you have to call `ros::spinOnce()`. If you don't need the while-loop, use `ros::spin()`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on 2018-07-30**:
Yeah your'e right . Thanks !

**Comment by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on 2018-07-30**:
It's working !!

**Comment by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) on 2020-05-06**:
Could you post the definitive code that works? I am interested. Thanks!